# Modifiers in solidity placement

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

Can

```
_;
```

be surrounded by other code? for example:

```
modifier foo {
    require(msg.value > 100, "Boo");
    _;
    globVar = 1010;
}
```

I am watching a tutorial, so I am not set up for tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can.

Code before the underscore gets executed before the function (that uses this modifier) - and code after the underscore is executed after the function.